# OnAudioFocusChangeListener is not executed when the audio is played and paused?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediarecorder

I am developing an application, in which i need to capture the audio being played. So i implemented OnAudioFocusChangeListener in my activity to listen for any audio changes. But the listener is not getting called when music is played or paused. Below is my code

```
public class AudioManagerExample extends Activity implements OnAudioFocusChangeListener{
  AudioReceiver adreceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AudioManager am =   (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    Log.d("AudioManager", "Inside on audio focus change");
}
```

}

Where am i wrong? Is there any alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Pushpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include

```
 am.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Change your code to

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

Comment: Thank you vipul. Can we request for 2 audiofocus in same listener. i.e for AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN and AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS? I added both in my class, but i am getting "invalid duration hint audio focus request is denied" error in log.

Comment: Even for gain, its coming sometimes and sometimes not coming.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private fun initOnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    val afChangeListener: AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener =
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener { focusChange ->
            when (focusChange) {
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                    viewModel.isAppLostAudioFocusLiveData.value = false
                }
                else -> {
                    viewModel.isAppLostAudioFocusLiveData.value = true
                }
            }
        }

    val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
            AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener).build()
        )
    } else {
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus(
            afChangeListener,
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN
        )
    }
}
```

[kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) [android10](/questions/tagged/android10) [api](/questions/tagged/api)