# how to find the start and end time of the music application in android?

Tags: android, audio, core-audio

I am developing an application which should capture the start and end time of Audio(FM /Music). I surfed a lot and got to know this can be achieved through audioFocusListener. I have implemented the listener but i am not getting the values properly. i.e This is not giving proper value, when the audio is gain the focus and lost the focus.
[OnAudioFocusChangeListener is not executed when the audio is played and paused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081465/onaudiofocuschangelistener-is-not-executed-when-the-audio-is-played-and-paused)
Is there any alternative way to implement the same?

```
public class AudioManagerExample extends Activity implements OnAudioFocusChangeListener{
 AudioReceiver adreceiver;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 AudioManager am =   (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
 am.requestAudioFocus(this,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
}

@Override
 public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
 Log.d("AudioManager", "Inside on audio focus change");
  if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
     Log.d("AudioManager", "audio focus gained");
  if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS)
     Log.d("AudioManager", "audio focus lossed"); 
  /* Here i am always getting value -1 */

 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get the end time of the audio by getduration() method.you can implement as mediaPlayer.getDuration();

Comment: @Akash: Thanks, But the thing is i need to call mediaPlayer.getDuration() method at some interval. But i can't get the time when music stops playing?

Comment: Hi, can you post your OnAudioFocusChangeListener code for capturing start and end time of audio.?

Comment: @ vishwa: I have edited my question and post the code. I have tried for both gained and loss but not getting correct values.

Answer (score 0):

i am pasting some code here so you can get idea, do as per your requirement..
hope this will help you,

```
public void updateProgressBar() 
{
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() 
{
       public void run()
       {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };
```

Comment: @ Hasmukh: Thanks for the reply, The method you showed is my current approach, but i  want to avoid the thread running continuously. So looking for alternative method.